# Twitter bootstrap side menu for mobile apps

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a cordova app with twitter bootstrap and i now require a side menu like this one http://jakiestfu.github.io/Snap.js/demo/apps/default.html or this one https://slideout.js.org/ that does not require too much hacking to get it to work with twitter bootstrap.

The navbar component collapses to form a vertical menu but does not extend left to where i would like it to be. Is there a method i can use to adopt the available navbar component to look like the snap.js example?.

Comment: Try BootsNav here is a link ....  http://bootsnav.danurstrap.com/nav-mobile-slide.html

Comment: Thanks mate. That is exactly what i was looking for.